# Weird results when inserting into std::map

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap

I was trying to debug my code in QtCreator and I noticed I got weird numbers when I used `insert()` with `std::map`. Inserting key/value works just fine for the first 5-6 insertions, and then suddenly when I insert the 6th value it changes all my keys and values to something like (1,1) for all of them or it repeats a pattern, for example (1,1) then (1,7) then (1,1) again and so on. 
What I'm trying to do is make a list of the edges of my mesh (which is just a cube now) from the data imported in an `.obj` file.

The type of my container is `std::map< std::pair< unsigned int, unsigned int >, short >`

```
std::map< std::pair< unsigned int, unsigned int >, short >::iterator it;
unsigned int v1, v2, v3;
unsigned int min, max;

// Loop through the faces of the mesh
for( unsigned int i = 0; i < m_nFaces; ++i )
{
     // Here I get the index to each vertex of the face
      v1 = m_face[ i ].getVertIndex( 0 ) + 1;
      v2 = m_face[ i ].getVertIndex( 1 ) + 1;
      v3 = m_face[ i ].getVertIndex( 2 ) + 1;

        // Fill in adjacency list for mesh with edges directed from lower numbered vertex to the higher numbered one
        // Make sure no pair is repeated by setting the left term of the pair to be always the min and the right term to the max
        min = v1 < v2 ? v1 : v2;
        max = v1 > v2 ? v1 : v2;
        // Check if tuple is already in the container
        it = m_edgeList.find( std::make_pair( min, max) );
        // Else, if returned iterator to map::end
        if( it == m_edgeList.end() )
        {
            // Add the new pair
            m_edgeList.insert( std::make_pair( std::pair< unsigned int, unsigned int > ( min, max ), 0 ) );
            m_boundaryEdgeList.insert( std::make_pair( std::pair< unsigned int, unsigned int > ( min, max ), 0 ) );
            m_nEdges++;
        }
        else
        {
            m_boundaryEdgeList.erase( std::make_pair( min, max ) );
        }

        min = v2 < v3 ? v2 : v3;
        max = v2 > v3 ? v2 : v3;
        it = m_edgeList.find( std::make_pair( min, max) );
        if( it == m_edgeList.end() )
        {
            m_edgeList.insert( std::make_pair( std::pair< unsigned int, unsigned int > ( min, max ), 0 ) );
            m_boundaryEdgeList.insert( std::make_pair( std::pair< unsigned int, unsigned int > ( min, max ), 0 ) );
            m_nEdges++;
        }
        else
        {
            m_boundaryEdgeList.erase( std::make_pair( min, max ) );
        }

        min = v1 < v3 ? v1 : v3;
        max = v1 > v3 ? v1 : v3;
        it = m_edgeList.find( std::make_pair( min, max) );
        if( it == m_edgeList.end() )
        {
            m_edgeList.insert( std::make_pair( std::pair< unsigned int, unsigned int > ( min, max ), 0 ) );
            m_boundaryEdgeList.insert( std::make_pair( std::pair< unsigned int, unsigned int > ( min, max ), 0 ) );
            m_nEdges++;
        }
        else
        {
            m_boundaryEdgeList.erase( std::make_pair( min, max ) );
        }

}
```

Now, the weird thing is that `m_boundaryEdgeList` is correct while `m_edgeList` gives me these funky numbers when debugging. Has anybody ever had this kind of weird thing with `std::map`?

I'm reading my data from an `.obj` file and these are the values that I'm trying to insert into the map

```
f 1/1/1 2/2/2 3/3/3
f 3/3/3 2/2/2 4/4/4
f 3/3/5 4/4/6 5/5/7
f 5/5/7 4/4/6 6/6/8
f 5/5/9 6/6/10 7/7/11
f 7/7/11 6/6/10 8/8/12
f 2/2/13 8/9/14 4/4/15
f 4/4/15 8/9/14 6/10/16
f 7/11/17 1/1/18 5/12/19
f 5/12/19 1/1/18 3/3/20
```

Here's a SSCCE http://pastebin.com/akHzzGNH

Comment: Did you step over your code? looks more like a logical error

Comment: Yes I did, [here](http://imgur.com/a/FFBIf) are two screenshots while debugging , in the first one the values are correct, then I do the next iteration and the values change

Comment: Please provide a SSCCE: http://sscce.org/

Comment: @VaughnCato [Here](http://pastebin.com/akHzzGNH) it is!

Comment: That's better, but it doesn't output anything.  Where are the funky numbers?

Comment: @VaughnCato Sorry, I was just using Debug mode and forgot [http://pastebin.com/UnXCt2jF](http://pastebin.com/UnXCt2jF), and apparently when I print out the values they are correct but when I'm debugging not? Am I being stupid? :O

Comment: In the debugger, what value are you printing, and what line are you on when you print it?

Comment: @VaughnCato While going through the for loop in `buildEdgeList()` I'm looking at the values as they are inserted into `m_edgeList` which I've set as an expression evaluator in Debug mode. The funky numbers happen when `i=3` and I'm inserting the pair (4,6) which is the 8th item in the `std::map`. I'm not printing anything in the for loop, I'm printing all the content of the `std::map` at the very end

Comment: What is the expression you are evaluating?

Comment: @VaughnCato I just put m_edgeList as it is to see the content of it as I'm inserting the elements

Comment: I'm not seeing anything strange.  What value in particular looks strange?  What line are you on when you first see the strange value?

Comment: Also, are you using a debug build?

Comment: @VaughnCato Yes I'm using a debug build. And this happens at line 44 (when stepping from line 44 to 45), when `i = 3`, so after a couple of iterations, and instead of inserting (4,6), so for example [7].first.first = 4 and [7].first.second = 6, I now have all the elements set to be either (1,3) or (2,3)

Comment: @yayaCode: I'm not seeing that.  With i=3, on line 44 after executing `m_edgeList.insert( std::make_pair( std::pair< unsigned int, unsigned int > ( min, max ), 0 ) );`, I have `m_edgeList[7].first.first==4 and m_edgeList[7].first.second==6`.

Comment: To get your code to compile, I had to add `#include <map>
#include <vector>`, so maybe there is something different about your setup.

Comment: @VaughnCato I really don't know what's going on here, as soon as I extract the values from the map for printing them out or do whatever with them they are okay, when I go step by step into the loop that fills is the map I just get the weird values. Well, as long as the values are correct in the end I'm happy, I might be doing something wrong while I debug? Probably.